# Retrieve datatable object prototype

Tags: javascript, datatables, prototype

I have many datatables throughout my application (version 1.10.10). I invoke them with

```
var myDt = $("#myId").DataTable({/*properties object*/});
```

I need access to the prototype of the object `myDt` to add once, and for all in my app, all the custom functions I need for datatables.
Using `$().DataTable.prototype` didn't work, neither did I find any "fn" properties inside the datatables data structure. I didn't find anything on the net about this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the datatables plugin you're using *uses* a prototype, you should be able to find it in the source looking for `.prototype` or `Object.create`, the former (`prototype`) being the property on functions that refers to the object that will be assigned as the prototype when that function is called via `new`, and the latter (`Object.create`) being a mechanism for creating an object with a specific prototype directly, without a constructor function and `new`.

In the worst case, on ES5+ browsers, you can get the prototype of an object using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2):

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(myDt);
```

...but that would require you to create a datatable before you could add the features, which seems clunky.

Answer (score 1):

See [API plug-in development](http://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/api) for more information.

> A new API method can be registered using the `$.fn.dataTable.Api.register()` static method.

Example:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function () {
    var sum = 0;

    for ( var i=0, ien=this.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        sum += this[i];
    }

    return sum;
} );
```

Example calls:

```
table.column(2).data().sum();
```

Comment: This seems to be a good way to achieve what I need, but it i not about prototypes. I assume dt proto is well hidden or even not available from outside, so it exposes functions to implement plug-ins. Yet, this method affects columns, or rows, instead I need a method related to the full table - I need to write a post-render method to be available in every and callable with: myDt.myMethod().

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#myId").dataTable()
```

If doesn't work you can use "data" to store the dataTable object on your own

```
$("#myId").data("myDt", myDt)
```

and get it later with:

```
$("#myId").data("myDt")
```

Comment: This code returns the table object itself, or its data. I uderstand how to apply mopdifications to a single table, but I need to apply properties to all tables, so I need access to datatables object prototype.